# If $u$ is a unit in $S$, then $u$ is a unit in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

I think the proof is fairly simple...but of course one of my big problems in math is overdoing simple problems. So..

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity, and let $S<R$ be a subring containing the identity.  Prove that if $u$ is a unit in $S$, then $u$ is a unit in $R$.  Show by example that the converse is false.

So, let $u$ be a unit in $S$.  By definition of a unit, there exists a $v\in S$ such that $1=uv=vu$.  However, since $1\in R$, then by closure, $uv\in R$, and thus, $u$ is a unit in $R$.

As far as the converse, take the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]=R$, and $S=\mathbb{Z}$.  If the converse was true, this would say that $i=
\sqrt{-1}\in S$, which is clearly false, since $1=-i\cdot i$.

How is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part: That’s not quite correct. You need to argue that $v ∈ R$ rather than $1 = uv ∈ R$.

For the counterexample: I think you should rather disprove that

> Whenever $S ⊂ R$ is a subring of a ring $R$, and $u ∈ S$ is a unit in $R$ (that is there is some $v ∈ R$ with $uv = 1$ in $R$) then $u$ is also a unit in $S$ (that is there is some $v' ∈ S$ with $uv' = 1$ in $S$).

Your example doesn’t work in that case. Rather think of $ℤ ⊂ ℚ$.

Comment: Okay, so then in $u\in S,$ then $u\in R$.  So there is a $w\in R$ so $1=uw=wu$...and so $v=w$?, so $v\in R$?

Comment: Just simply use $S ⊂ R$. If for some $u ∈ S$ there is some $v ∈ S$ with $uv = 1$, then – as $S ⊂ R$ – both $u$ and $v$ are also in $R$.